# Userform TextBox not Reading Large Numbers

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I have a userform that opens a userform if condition 1 or condition 2 are met, if not then it opens a msgbox. Condition 1 is `If deptotal.Value > "250,000"` and Condition 2 is `equitytotal.Value > "80"`. I was testing it out and for some reason my userform wont open a value of 100,000,000, even though it is greater than 250,000. It will work with 300,000,000. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my full code:

```
Private Sub rec_Click()

    If deptotal.Value > "250,000" Or equitytotal.Value > "80" Then

        UserForm4.Show

    Else

        If deptotal.Value < "250,000" Or equitytotal.Value < "80" Then

            MsgBox "No Recommendations to Show as of Now"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are probably comparing a numeric value with a string. Remove the quotes around the numbers (and the comma in 250000) and try again.

Comment: @FunThomas thanks, that worked!

Comment: @FunThomas for some reason the useform appears now even if 'deptotal.value ' or 'equitytotal.value' are balnk

Comment: If `deptotal.value` is blank and `equitytotal.Value` has a value > 80, of course the userform shows up - that't the idea of an `Or` in an `If`-statement

Comment: @JoseCortez: But you used an `Or` operator, so if one of the values is OK then the loop will fire. Check your logic- because you have some overlapping cases here.